# Why aren't these the characteristics to my PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, cauchy-problem

I am solving this Cauchy problem:
(x+y^2)u_x+yu_y+(x/y-y)u=1 where the initial condition is $u(x,1)=0$. The solution is $(x(s,t),y(s,t),z(s,t))=(e^{2t}+(s-1)e^t,e^t,1/(s-1)+e^{t(1-s)}/(1-s))$. I thought that this meant that my characteristics where $(e^{2t}+(s-1)e^t,e^t)$. However, if $g(t)=u(e^{2t}+(s-1)e^t,e^t)$ then
$$g'(t)=u_x(2e^{2t}+(s-1)e^t)+u_ye^t=u_ x(x+y^2)+u_yy\neq 0 \quad \text{(according to my equation)}$$
Why aren't these the caracteristics? How can I find them?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is a function of $x$ and $y$ only. Why $s$ and $t$ are still appearing in your proposed solution ?

Since the steps of your calculus are not edited one cannot says where exactly is the hitch.

$$(x+y^2)u_x+y\,u_y=1-(\frac{x}{y}-y)u$$
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{x+y^2}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{1-(\frac{x}{y}-y)u}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{x+y^2}=\frac{dy}{y}$ :
$$y-\frac{x}{y}=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{1+c_1u}$ :
$$(1+c_1u)y^{-c_1}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE on the form of implicit equation $c_2=F(c_1)$  is :
$$(1+(y-\frac{x}{y})u)y^{-(y-\frac{x}{y})}=F(y-\frac{x}{y})$$
$F$ is an arbitraty function until no condition is taken into account.

$$\boxed{u(x,y)=\frac{y^{(y-\frac{x}{y})}F(y-\frac{x}{y})-1}{y-\frac{x}{y}}}$$

CONDITION $u(x,1)=0$ :
$$u(x,1)=\frac{1^{(1-\frac{x}{1})}F(1-\frac{x}{1})-1}{(1-\frac{x}{1})}=0$$

$$F(1-x)=1$$
Thus $F$ is the constant function $F=1$.

The particular solution which satisfies both the PDE and the condition  is :

$$\boxed{u(x,y)=\frac{y^{(y-\frac{x}{y})}-1}{y-\frac{x}{y}}}$$